# How can I move all the window controls (minimize,maximize,close) to the left?

Tags: windows-xp

How can I move all the window controls (minimize,maximize,close) to the left on Windows XP?

It is default in modern Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

LeftSider is a small portable tool which immediately moves the Title bar buttons (Minimize, Maximize, Close) to the left side, just like you will find in Mac OS X operating system. It is useful for only those users who are used to having such buttons on the left side in the title bar.

On launch, the application will sit in the system tray and immediate move all Title bar buttons to the left side. To undo this action and restore back to default, simply close the application from the system tray.

close button left side windows 7

To make sure the program runs on Windows startup, add the executable file in the Startup Folder. Originally developed for Windows Vista, it works on both Windows XP and Windows 7.

link is : http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/move-windows-close-minimize-buttons-to-left-side-like-mac-os-x/